# Changing a websites favicon with a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to put together a Chrome extension that changes (or overrides) a websites favicon and replaces it with a different image. I've found nothing on it when searching, so I'm assuming this can't be done? It doesn't really matter to me if it's done in Javascript or html; I would just like to know if it's possible at all. All help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Manifest have a field for icon google for chrome app manifest

Comment: @vkubre I'm having trouble understanding what you mean

Comment: Creating chrome extension require a manifest file included in your project directory, In manifest file you can specify fields like icon, name, etc. Link:- https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest

Comment: @vkubre That's for giving **the extension** an icon, which isn't what the OP is asking how to do.

Comment: I see the icon settings in the manifest files, but it only changes the extensions favicon, when I want to change a websites favicon image, like [this](https://puu.sh/xnJQe/63cc71bf15.png)

Comment: Of course it's possible and rather trivial: use a content script of your extension and replace or add `link` element with `rel` attribute that contains any of the popular values like 'icon' or 'image' or others specific for Apple devices.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can. 
There are two ways to do that:

#### 1. Using content-script

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",

    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "js": ["content-script.js"],
          "run_at": "document_end"
        }
    ]
}
```

**content-script.js**

```js
document.querySelector('link[rel*="icon"]').href = "//placehold.it/32/F00"
```

#### 2. Using background script + code injection

**manifest.json**

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Extension",
    "version": "1.0.0",

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "permissions": [
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ]
}
```

**background.js**

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo) => {
    if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {
            code: 'document.querySelector(\'link[rel*="icon"]\').href = "//placehold.it/32/F00"'
        });
    }
});
```

P.S. consider to choose better selector than `link[rel*="icon"]`

**Update #1**

The example above shows how to load new icon from an external resource. 

As an alternative, it is also available to use `base64` representation of an image or put an icon inside the extension bundle and request it using [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources) and [chrome.runtime.getURL](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL)

Comment: could you change this answer to show setting one that is not a URL? can you set on within the extension?

Comment: @NicholasDiPiazza do you want to set your own url or selector?

Comment: i ended up just putting the image on our website so that it resolves as a full URL. but i was wondering how to use an image bundled inside your extension

Comment: ah! i always forget you can do that

Comment: I'm failing to get this working using manifest_version 3:
`The "background.scripts" key cannot be used with manifest_version 3. Use the "background.service_worker" key instead.`