# Set the browser's tab background color with browser extension/addon

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, browser-extension

Is there any way of setting the browser's tab background color (not the favicon image) and text color with the help of an browser extension/addon.

I've searched the internet to and fro and found nothing in the APIs. So I think it is not possible. But maybe someone has a solution for that.

What I want to achieve is to tint the colors of TYPO3 tabs according to the application context (Development, Production/Staging, Staging). I managed to set the top-bar color in the TYPO3 backend depending in the application context, so the logic works well. What I'd like to have now is a way of tinting the tab.

Comment: No such API in Chrome. In FF there's browser.theme.

Answer (score 2):

You are right: there's nothing in Firefox or Chrome API that allows you to color individual tabs easily. But there are some workaround ideas..

[Colorful Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/colorfultabs/) uses theme override to style individual tabs, including (by default) based on domain, using the `browser.theme` API that only Firefox supports. However, after trying it out, it might not fit your requirements: in current Firefox version it only affects the color of the currently selected tab (and the address bar), not providing you with a good overview.

Some other extensions for Firefox, for example [TST Colored Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tst-colored-tabs/) use sidebar tab representation that duplicates the tab bar, with possible enhancements. Also not ideal, and also Firefox-specific.

For Chrome, there's a Chrome-specific API [`tabGroups`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabGroups/) that can add color outline to tabs, but only by adding them to a group. You can have many groups, but it's still going to be ugly if your tabs are interspersed or moved around.

**So let me propose an out of the box solution:** use a custom favicon per application context instead of trying to change how the tab UI looks. That would be always visible in the tabs strip without any code on the browser's part. You could also [override favicons from extension code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45972000/934239) if there's no easy way to do it on the application side.